# forwarding traffic between the ports

Tags: infiniband

How to set up forwarding traffic between interfaces "HCA"? I want to implement a ring topology.

1. PC

Listing GUIDs:

- Port 0: 0x2c903000f6d27
- Port 1: 0x2c903000f6d28

  2. PC

Listing GUIDs:

- Port 0: 0x2c90300048975
- Port 1: 0x2c90300048976

  3. PC

Listing GUIDs:

- Port 0: 0x2c9030004a773
- Port 1: 0x2c9030004a774

I cannot ping through the port. How to set up routes or forwarding traffic?

Comment: How are the ports connected? Why do you need forwarding if it it is just 3 machines?

Comment: are connected by the so - 1 pc (1 port) - 2 pc (2 port), 2 pc (1 port) - 3 PCs (2 port) 3 pc (1 port) - 1 pc (2 port), later to be 5 pc without switch ( 2 PC hypervisor) . Infiniband use as a transport for SAN

Comment: With 3 PCs connected like that, I don't think you need forwarding, but with 5 you will. You can set up IP forwarding with IPoIB, but I don't think InfiniBand supports in general forwarding RDMA connections like that.

Comment: do not tell me where you can read about this topic? Yes I want RDMA transport

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know. I don't think there's some document forbidding someone from implementing what you ask for. It's just that I don't know of any such implementation.